# French typography: space before percent sign

Tags: spacing, babel, french

I have come across another specific typography rule in French: one must put a non-breaking space before the percentage sign (see this handy [cheat-sheet](http://michel.balmont.free.fr/info/typo/tablotypo.html)). This is also true for colons, semi-colons, exclamation and interrogation signs. The babel package documentation states that this is taken into account and that it does this spacing automatically so that the forgetful users do not need to write this space before these symbols. It seems, however, that the percentage sign is not considered among these.

**Question:** why is the percentage sign not *actively spaced* in french babel?

This is easy to resolve with a redefinition of `\%` like:

```
\let\oldpercent=\%
\renewcommand{\%}{\ifmmode\oldpercent\else\thinspace\oldpercent\fi}
```

it just seems weird that babel did not do it automatically. Moreover, the spanish option does the separation. Maybe this is a bug of the frenchb/french language option or it is me who is misinformed?

---

Related questions: [Paragraph spacing in other languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7218/paragraph-spacing-in-other-languages)

Comment: I guess that the issue here is that `:`, _etc._, are punctuation, but `%` is notreally. It's a unit, of sorts, and so desereves different handling. (To be honest, I always think `babel` is a bit of a mess.)

Comment: You might want to use the `siunitx` package to deal with the formating of numbers with units.

Comment: I agree with @Joseph Wright: `%` is not a punctuation but a unit. This would justify the fact that babel does not handle it. However, the fact that it is handled in the Spanish version contradicts the justification (and in Spanish it is not a punctuation symbol either). In other words, babel should either handle it or not for all languages. So, yes, babel is a bit of a mess. But most languages are a mess :-)

Comment: I also agree with @Frédéric, I will use `siunitx` and be done with it. If either of you wants to answer this question, I will accept it then.

Comment: I've summarised things into an answer of sorts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iguess that the issue here is that `:`, *etc.*, are punctuation, but `%` is not really. It's a unit, of sorts, and so deserves different handling. (To be honest, I always think `babel` is a bit of a mess: for consistency French and Spanish should treat `%` in the same way.)

As has been pointed out, there are packages available for handling units, including `%`, for example my own [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx).